# Requirement already satisfied but ImportError: No module named "pkg"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am Using `Mac` and `Pycharm` & `Python 2.7.11`,

```
import psutil
import os
```

I have installed some pkg already but

```
ImportError: No module named "pkg" shows at IDE
```

and Terminal Shows: `Requirement already satisfied: psutil in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Still, Now I am facing this issue. But at Some cases, things have been solved like I had two Python 2.7.10 & 2.7.11 installed.From mac terminal, I used pkg for 2.7.11 but at Project Settings Python Interpreter was selected as 2.7.10.